# L1 constrained Regression in C

Tags: c, mathematical-optimization

I need Lasso/L1 constrained Regression Library in C. AFAIK, NAG does not support it. R has a package to do it but I need to do it in C. Any idea?

Comment: What libraries can you use?  I wrote my own C version, which is really not that hard TBH.  You can use the CRAN version as a prototype

Comment: thanks. I used my own. It worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks. I wrote my own C function and it worked well.

Comment: Can you provide your solution ?

Comment: @dwbrito Here's the implentation in C, in bbr package. All code & executables are hosted at Google Code project page. Main page http://www.bayesianregression.org/ and project page http://code.google.com/p/bbrbmr/downloads/list

Answer (score 2):

You could embed R in your application.

Answer (score 2):

Coding l1 stuff yourself should not be too bad. Both ftp://ftp.math.ucla.edu/pub/camreport/cam08-37.pdf and ftp://ftp.math.ucla.edu/pub/camreport/cam08-29.pdf are easy to implement.

If you can use C++ this library might already have what you want:
http://www.di.ens.fr/willow/SPAMS/index.html